# Display category and its content in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I am using TYPO3 6.2.9 CMS.I make category and assigned to page.But I don't know how to display the category when i am showing the page i want all the category assign to that page must display then after clicking that category the content which i have assign to that category must display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the box solution for this.

But you can use the following :
Or create your own extension where you gather the categories of your page and render them on your page. You then can also create a sort of category menu. 
You can use category collection :
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html

cObject RECORDS has also a categories property, so you could also use typoscript for rendering.

Comment: thanks....but actually i dont know where to put this content which is there in your mention link..means from which files to start or from admin i need to start...very confused..please guide me

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use extensions to your website.
[Catalogue extension package](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/titech_catalog/)
Which relates to categorisers and if you want to you can customize it in your own manner.
Use of these extensions make simple in listing category.

The usage is also given in its manual ans its simple to adopt it.